# Convert a timestamp to an .ics iCal compatible date format

Tags: php, icalendar

I have a date that I am storing as a timestamp through the [formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) function in jQuery.  I am then retriving this value to make an ics file, a calender file that adds the event time and details to the users calender.  However the timestamp format isn't working in the ics file, the correct date isn't being added, so I need to convert it to a value that looks like `20091109T101015Z`.  It's current format as a timestamp looks like `1344466800000`This is from [this example](http://www.myhow2guru.com/archives/php-generate-calendar-file-ics/) which is what I am following to create my ics file.

My link to the php file is  http:// domain. com/icsCreator.php?startDate=1344380400000&endDate=1345503600000&event=Space%20Weather%20Workshop&location=London

Current my ics file looks like

```
<?php
$dtStart=$_GET['startDate'];
$dtEnd=$_GET['endDate'];
$eventName=$_GET['event'];
$location=$_GET['location'];

...
echo "CREATED:20091109T101015Z\n";
echo "DESCRIPTION:$eventName\n";
echo "DTEND:$dtEnd\n";    
echo "DTSTART:".$dtStart."\n";
echo "LAST-MODIFIED:20091109T101015Z\n";
echo "LOCATION:$location\n";
...

?>
```

Comment: Could you delete all lines that don't belong to the date question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if this works:

```
date('Ymd\THis', $time)
```

Here `$time` could be `startDate` or `endDate` from your query string. If you don't want the time:

```
date('Ymd', $time)
```

**NOTE** (Thanks to Nicola) Here, `$time` must be a valid UNIX timestamp i.e. it must represent the number of seconds since the epoch. If it represents the number of milliseconds, you need to first divide it by 1000.

**EDIT** As pointed out by *lars k*, you need to add `\Z` to the end of both the strings.

**EDIT** As pointed out by *Nicola*, you don't really need it.

Comment: thanks, it is putting a date in now which is wasn't doign before, but it's the wrong ones, I'm getting start time 6/10/71 and end time 10/5/2007!

Comment: You might want to divide your timestamp by 1000. Is it in milliseconds?

Comment: @RohanPrabhu that worked!  I changed my vars to $dtStart=date('Ymd',$_GET['startDate']/1000);
$dtEnd=date('Ymd',$_GET['endDate']/1000); and that now works brilliantly

Comment: @Nicola: I saw that in the example that you gave me. If it works without it.. great...

Comment: Do you want to just edit your answer to show it needs to be divided by 1000 and I will mark it correct?

Comment: Well, I was assuming that the timestamp would be in seconds (because that is how it is supposed to be), but I have added a note.

Comment: @Nicola According to the RFC (2445), the Z means that it's a UTC time.

Comment: I want display time first followed by date how to do that in ICS file

Answer (score 5):

The \Z is telling the system the timezone. Z being Zulu or Universal time.

If you leave that out - then you are presuming that the timezone settings on the end users calendar application, match those of your system generating the timestamps.

In the USA alone there are multiple timezones - so you can't make that assumption just based on your users being in the same country as you.

In order for dates to go into the calendar correctly, you need to specify the timezone offset from UTC as plus or minus Hours and Minutes

NOTE:
    date('Ymd\THisP') ; // P is an offset against GMT and should work for all calendar purposes.

That would out put somthing like this for a 1hr shift from GMT

```
20150601T10:38+01:00
```

When working with Dates in PHP it's best to use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, then you can easily work with and change the [timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

```
// Start with your local timezone e.g
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam') ; 

// Don't be tempted to use a timezone abbreviation like EST
// That could mean Eastern Standard Time for USA or Australia.
// Use a full timezone: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

$eventdate = new DateTime ( '1st September 2015 10:30', $timezone);

// Convert the time to Universal Time
$eventdate->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone('UTC') ) ; // Universal / Zulu time

// Return Event Date/Time in calendar ICS friendly format 
// comfortable in the knowledge that it is really in UTC time
return $eventdate->format('Ymd\THis\Z') ;
```